# Can't edit the content of the draggable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, draggable

I have this block of code which I also adapted from the internet:

```
<script>
    $.count = 1;
    $(function() {
        $('#object1')
            .click(function(){
                var htmlData='<div id="'+$.count+'" class="draggable ui-widget-content ui-draggable" style="height:100px; width:100px;';
                htmlData += '"';
                htmlData += '><div id="editable'+$.count+'" style="color:black">Object</div><div id="pos'+$.count+'X"></div><div id="pos'+$.count+'Y"></div></div>';
                $('.demo').append(htmlData);
                $('.draggable').draggable({
                    drag: function(){
                        var offset1 = $(this).offset();
                        var xPos1 = offset1.left;
                        var yPos1 = offset1.top;
                        var element = $(this).attr('id');
                        $('#pos'+element+'X').text('x: ' + xPos1);
                        $('#pos'+element+'Y').text('y: ' + yPos1);
                    }
            })
            .resizable()
            .mousedown(function(ev) {
                 $(this).draggable('disable');
            }).mouseup(function(ev) {
                 $(this).draggable('enable');
            });
            $.count++;
        });
    });

</script>

<div class='demo'></div>
```

Basically what I'm doing is making draggable textbox dynamically. Now, I'm trying edit the text in the div of any textbox created but it can't be changed, it just highlights if clicked then when I release my mouse, it returns back to its original state. Actually, I want to integrate this code http://jsfiddle.net/cSMYG/121/ to what I'm doing. What that does is editing the text in the div.

Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/VRTf8/1/
I can't edit the content of the objects

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle for your problem?

Comment: I've added the sample.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is indirectly answering your question, but you can specify a handle as part of your draggable code so that only part of a given element triggers the drag event.

Here is a simplified version of the code [JSFiddle Version](http://jsfiddle.net/VRTf8/4/):

```
$('#object1').click(function(){
    var newBox = $("<div>", {id: $.count, class: "mybox"})
        .append($("<div>", {class: "boxtitle"}).html("Object"))
        .append($("<div>", {class: "boxcediv", contenteditable: true}));
    newBox.draggable({handle: ".boxtitle"}).resizable();
    $.count++;
    $('.demo').append(newBox);
});
```

This creates a div with both a 'title' and a contenteditable area to input text. The title is set as the handle so that you can drag the box around using that.

Hopefully this at least helps you get in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

Just to be sure, the Fiddle you linked to includes [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)
.  Are you including it in your page?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I include jQuery UI.